# Maven Plugin for Validating JSON Files

Tags: json, maven

I am looking for a maven plugin that will simply compare a json file with an associated JSON Schema file. Essentially we are getting plagued with invalid configuration files which are only run in a single environment. So testing of the "dev" environment will pass with flying colors though when the application is launched with the "prod" configurations the application will fail to start is the config is say missing a comma or otherwise the JSON doesn't parse.

Looking for a non-intrusive solution to verify that the config files are at least in the expected format before marking the build as successful (say like within a CI environment).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posting this for completeness. The maven plugin was opensourced by Groupon and can be found here : https://github.com/groupon/json-schema-validator

Answer (score 0):

Lacking a Maven plugin, I would do this with a small Java unit test which runs a schema validator over your example inputs - you could use a Maven filter to choose which file to parse based on your environment. If all configurations are stored in your SCM, you should be able to validate all configurations with one unit test.

If you're looking for a library to use in your unit test, have a look at the JSON schema validator:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.fge</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
```

Another thought - if your configuration needs runtime validation, you should use the above library to validate when it changes. If you make your configuration update process interactive, you could validate as it changes and reject configuration updates which are invalid.